# FIND THE MINIMUM VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I wrote a code to find the minimum students age, but it doesn't work.

```sql
SELECT 
  S.stuName,
  (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(S.stuBirthdate)) AS AGE
FROM tblStudent S
WHERE (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(S.stuBirthdate)) <= ALL   
        (SELECT(YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(S.stuBirthdate))
            FROM tblStudent )
```

Can You help with solving this issue, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong alias usage. Give a separate alias to the table in the subquery. Currently you  compare every student with him/herself.

```
SELECT 
  S.stuName,
  (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(S.stuBirthdate)) AS AGE
FROM tblStudent S
WHERE (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(S.stuBirthdate)) <= ALL   
        (SELECT(YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(t2.stuBirthdate))
            FROM tblStudent t2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
  SELECT 
    S.stuName,
    (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(S.stuBirthdate)) AS AGE
  FROM tblStudent S
  WHERE stuBirthDate = (
    SELECT MAX(stuBirthdate) FROM tblStudent
  ) -- Get birthdate of youngest student
```

Comment: i want to show all the  youngest  , your code just show 1 answer :(( how can we show all the youngest age student ?

Comment: What do you mean all the "highest"?  Minimum implies "lowest".  Do you mean if there are 3 students with the same "minimum" age of 20, you want to return all 3 rows?

Comment: sr , i mean the list of the student with minimum age

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```sql
SELECT S.stuName, MIN(YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(S.stuBirthdate)) AS AGE FROM tblStudent S GROUP BY S.stuName
```

Comment: STILL NOT WORKING :< BUT THE NAME OF STUDENT NAME IS ORGANIZE FROM A TO Z

Comment: what do you want to get? the one minimum age or one minimum student with age or list of the student with minimum age?

Comment: yup,list of the student with minimum age

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the list of students with the minimum age is to use `SELECT TOP WITH TIES` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES S.stuName,
       (YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(S.stuBirthdate)) AS AGE
FROM tblStudent S
ORDER BY AGE ASC;
```